# Can we provide a REST API end point so that SoftLayer can callback after BareMetal provisioning request is complete?

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Since a BareMetal provisioning request does not come back recently quickly like CCI provisioning request, is it possible for SoftLayer to call back to a REST API end point I provide?

Answer (score 0):

currently Softlayer's API does not support call backs.

When you order a Bare Metal server the result of the request returns a global Identifier you can use this global identifier to call the [getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/getObject) method, when you call the method you will notice that "provisionDate" is null, when the field is updated that means that your bare metal server is ready. So you can use this beahvior to know when your server is ready, you just need to make repeadly requests to verify that field is updated (Note: Also the Id will be updated when the server is ready).

Regards